# Can I start the speechrecognizer in listen mode and invisible to the user?

Tags: c#, xna, speech

I'm using the speechrecognizer in C# to create a basic grammar and listen for commands.

Since I'm developing this grammar/system to be used for a small game/app I'm making, I'd
love to start the speech recognizer in listen mode and invisible (or at the very least condense it
down to the taskbar). My biggest concern is that if the game ever gets any recognition (lol)
that people will be turned off by the obtrusiveness of the windows SR.

So, Can I start the speech recognizer in listen mode, and invisible to the user?
And can I close it when the app is finished so that the user doesn't ever actually deal with
the SR program, just my program/game?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a SpeechRecognitionEngine class that allows you to do exactly what I was wanting.

Just wanted to let everyone know. Here is the documentation for that class from microsofts website:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.aspx

Enjoy.